# MySql Can I use a function to set md5 value of another colum?

Tags: mysql

Table with
field abd text
field hash_code varchar

I would like to have in hash_code the md5 value of abd field without to do so from the code.

is that possibile?
Thanks

Comment: Have you read about [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)?

Comment: yeah and I could not find a way.

Comment: [MD5() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> create table mytable ( abd varchar(100), hash_code char(32) as (md5(abd)) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into mytable set abd = 'now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from mytable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      abd: now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country
hash_code: 60a5d53255faa66033c9851adb40947a
```